# Javascript regex replace next match

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, match

Many questions you might think are related will say something like "use /g". That's not what I'm after. There must be a way to do this. What I have is the following:

```
<script>
var myString = "DECLARE DeCLARE Declare DECLARE";
var arr = myString.match(new RegExp("[Dd]eclare|DECLARE","gm"));
var clr = "#F00";
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
{
    myString = myString.replace(arr[i],"-"+arr[i]+"-");
}
document.write(myString);
</script>
```

The output:

```
--DECLARE-- DeCLARE -Declare- DECLARE
```

Desired output:

```
-DECLARE- DeCLARE -Declare- -DECLARE-
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a capturing group in the global regex, and use the captured value in the `.replace()`.

```
var myString = "DECLARE DeCLARE Declare DECLARE";

// ---capture-----------v------------------v
var regex = new RegExp("([Dd]eclare|DECLARE)","gm");

// ---first capture------------------v
myString = myString.replace(regex,"-$1-");

document.write(myString); // "-DECLARE- DeCLARE -Declare- -DECLARE-"
```